# How to include 'Survey Weights' in a Proportional-Odds (Cumulative Logit) model

Tags: bayesian, ordered-logit, weighted-data, weights, survey-weights

I am looking to design a Bayesian multilevel Proportional Odds model, which incorporates the use of survey weights in JAGS.

The inclusion of weights for linear and Poisson models appears straightforward, however I suspect the process is a more complicated procedure for a Proportional Odds model.

**Linear: y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau / weight[i])**

**Poisson: y[i] ~ dpois(lambda[i] * weight[i])**

I would like to know how survey weights are included in a Proportional-Odds (also known as the Cumulative Logit) model. I understand that weights may be incorporated when designing frequentist models with the clmm function in the [R] package 'ordinal' [1](ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/ordinal/ordinal.pdf).

**This is a question specific to data modelling.** For completeness, I have included JAGS sample code for the unweighted model beneath, to demonstrate the design of these models.

```
polr_model <- model{

## N = Number of observations
## y = Outcome measured as an ordinal variable (with categories 1,2,3,4,5)
## Categories = Number of y-variable categories (5)
## variable1 = numeric x-variable
## variable2 = numeric x-variable
## Geography = level-2 hierachical struture, in which observations are nested
## weights = survey weights (NOT CURRENTLY USED)

for(i in 1:N){

    ## Calculate categorical likelihood of the outcome:
    y[i] ~ dcat(prob[i,1:Categories])

    ## The odds is fixed between observation categories
    ## This is the same as any LR except that the intercept isnt included here:

    odds[i] <- b1 * variable1[i] + b2 * variable2[i] + 
                randomeffect[Geography[i]]

    ## Each observation category is associated with a cumualtive probability called theta:
    for(k in 1:(Categories-1)){
        ## Each observation category has its own intercept - note the minus sign here NOT plus:
        logit(theta[i,k]) <- intercept[k] - odds[i]
    }
    ## With the cumulative probability of the highest category equal to 1:
    theta[i, Categories] <- 1

    ## Then calculate the non-cumulative probabilities from theta:
    prob[i,1] <- theta[i,1]
    for(k in 2:(Categories-1)){
        prob[i,k] <- theta[i,k] - theta[i,(k-1)]
    }
    prob[i, Categories] <- 1 - theta[i,(Categories-1)]
}

## These lines give the prior distributions for the numeric fixed parameters to be estimated:
b1 ~ dnorm(0, 10^-6)
b2 ~ dnorm(0, 10^-6)

## Calculate the Categories-1 independent intercepts::
for(k in 1:(Categories-1)){
    intercept[k] ~ dnorm(0, 10^-6)
}

## These lines give the prior distributions for the 'random' (hierachical/nested) parameters to be estimated:
for(iterator in 1:Nest1){
    randomeffect[iterator] ~ dnorm(0, Geography_precision)}
Geography_precision ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001)


#data#      N, Nest1, Categories, y, variable1, variable2,    Geography
#monitor#   intercept, b1, b2, randomeffect 
#inits#     Geography_precision, intercept, b1, b2
#modules#   glm on, lecuyer on  
}
```

Comment: Does the weighting relate to variables that you can condition on in the regression model?  Conditioning leads to higher precision than weighting.

Comment: Specific to my complete model:
(a) For the preceding analysis, a set of optimised survey weights were created based on gender, education, perceived rurality and location. These terms are included in the model, however there are some differences: education is recorded across an expanded range, and location is recorded at a reduced spatial resolution to ensure that the multilevel models abide to Hox’s (1998) 50/20 group-observation rule.

Comment: (b) In running a frequentist version of my model in the ‘ordinal’ package I have found improved performance by including the weights (in terms of AIC, pseudo-R2, and coefficient significances), for only a very small cost in the standard errors.

Comment: If the variables were a direct match, one line of though is that survey weights may be redundant, Frank, as you mention such influences are already conditioned by the model. This is very useful piece of information to know.
However, in my case it looks like the inclusion of weights would be an advantage. Therefore, I would still like to understand how I should use these to inform a Proportional Odds model

Comment: I am dubious about the 'advantage'.  To upweight some observations you must downweight others, resulting in a lower effective sample size.  The standard errors are the gold standards here.